# Terminal Command not working to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp

I'm working on a Mac 10.6.6 with MAMP installed.

Previously, I have been able to connect to mysql using this from my command line

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8889 --user=root -p
```

but now it is saying

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem?
[image: mysql directory]

Comment: In which directory do you have the `mysql` client program installed? Is that directory in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: MAMP is installed in the /Applications directory.   I don't really understand what you're talking about when you mention PATH environment variable. However, I never had to do anything special before.  Can you explain to me how to check it?

Comment: @Michael, from the shell, run `echo $PATH` to see what I mean for the `PATH` environment variable. (Details on the environment variables is probably in the `man environ` manpage.) If the `/Applications/MAMP/` directory isn't in your `PATH`, you can edit your `/.bash_profile` or `/.profile` (pick whichever one exists already) file and add `PATH=/Applications/MAMP_whatever/:$PATH`. Make sure the `mysql` client program is actually _in_ whatever directory you specify :)

Comment: @sarnold the problem is, if you look at my amended OP, there are mysql folders inside other mysql folders, so I don't know which one to end the path at.

Comment: @sarnold also, you're PATH= construction is different from @Neo so I don't know which one to use. I.e. his has "export" yours doesn't etc.

Comment: @Michael, end the path at whichever one has a `mysql` executable binary inside. :) Maybe @Neo's right, does WAMP in the end install its tools into `/usr/include/mysql/bin`? The `export` command is included to make sure that `PATH` is exported to child programs; it usually is :) so there's no point in re-exporting it. (It won't hurt if you do.)

Comment: It doesn't hurt to test a new PATH with export, it will be reset when you close your terminal. It it works and doesn't break anything else, add it to your profile.

Answer (score 6):

add to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/postgre/bin
export PATH
```

Then, in an existing terminal: `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: thanks, can you clarify a few things about your answer. (1) will this work with mysql that is installed via MAMP that is in the Applications folder?  (2) does the last line in your answer (i.e. source~/.bash_profile) also go into the file?

Comment: currently, my .bash_profile is totally blank. Is that a problem? Also, if you look at my amended OP, I have a pic of my file directory which shows that there are mysql folders inside other mysql folders, so I don't know which one to end the path at.

Comment: /usr/local/your_mysql_directory_path/bin

Answer (score 4):

So, to get back to the question about MAMP, I'm going to try to simplify @SnapShot's answer.

Edit your bash profile (using whatever text editor you like, but in the example below it's using vi:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Then insert

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this:

Probably the best way is to type at the terminal:

vi ~/.bash_profile

and add

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
```

to your path statement
and then run

source ~/.bash_profile

Depending on how much you run it you can also just type in:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

or make an alias like this:

```
alias m='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql --host=localhost --port=8889 --user=root -p'
```

then just typing m will start it for you.

You can also make a shell script to pass different parameters if you login as a different user:

vi ~/m.sh

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql --host=localhost --port=8889 --user=$1 -p
```

and run it by using sh ~/m.sh username

Also, if you only use those same parameters you don't really to include them - they are the defaults for MAMP.  You can just run the mysql commmand without them.